# Salesforce: Google maps query status 620 G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES

Tags: google-maps, salesforce

In Salesforce I have created a future method that makes a Google Maps geocode callout.  I know there is a limit of 2,500 requests per day but our instance has made no more than 100 requests today. Maybe the same number of requests yesterday.   Yet the response code is 620 G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES.

Could it be that Google is seeing the IP address of the instance of Salesforce and aggregating all of these requests as coming from one location. So other companies that are sharing the address are causing my instance to hit this limit?
If not can anyone suggest another cause?

Answer (score 3):

[This discussion](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Google-Maps-API-G-GEO-TOO-MANY-QUERIES/td-p/101780) suggests that it is the shared origin from salesforce that is messing it up.
This only makes sense though if you are doing the geocode lookup from the server and not from a client. If you would do it fromt the client it would use the ip from the client and you are dealing with the local clients lookup limits (see below).

If you are doing it on the server you might also have to check if you are actually doing something that is legal and not breaking the ToS from google. In [this discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-api@googlegroups.com/msg55169.html) you will get some background on that and also a solution if you need to fix this on the server (buy a licence)

To be complete the G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES can mean one of 2 things:

- You exceeded the daily limit (too many in a day)
- You exceeded the speed limit (too many request is too short period)

Google has not specified an exact limit as far as I know but they don't seem to enjoy automated lookups. If you look at various libraries and plugins you'll see that all of them force a delay between each request and often they add a little randomness to the delay. You could experiment with this if it makes any difference

Comment: Yes the future method will be running on the server. So it seems that our code that make a few calls to the map api, can hit these limits because others on the same server are doing the same.  I'll need to read into the ToS and how to buy a licence.  Once I find this information and confirm your idea then I'll mark your post as an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did this end up working for you?  we're hitting a server-side 620 and all configuration looks a.o.k... we have a premier license and upgraded to 250k requests per day.

Comment: oops...   i thought i was adding a comment to the other thread... I'm awesome!

Comment: I concluded that making Google Map API calls from the Salesforce server could, randomly, hit the G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES error.  Our business needs changed so I stopped looking into this further, for now.

Comment: I figured out that our issue was that my httpRequest url was formatted for the 'free' version of the api.  There were some different properties (aside from key) that need to be set to get the upgraded version of the api to be cool.... the more you know...